# Efficient method of obtaining successive high values of data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, rowfilter

Lets say I have the following data.frame in R

```
df <- data.frame(order=(1:10),value=c(1,7,3,5,9,2,9,10,2,3))
```

Other than looping through data an testing whether value exceeds previous high value how can I get successive high values so that I can end up with a table like this

```
order   value
 1        1
 2        7
 5        9
 8       10
```

TIA

Comment: I created a new tag [tag:cumulative-max] for you. I don't appreciate that the other answerer gets to piggyback off my work asking you for clarity.

Comment: @smci, I posted my answer after I saw that your edited answer _after_ you understood the question as "filter rows whose value is higher than previous max" was still different from what I understood the question to be. I think that's a normal process on SO, isn't it?

Comment: @beginneR: The normal process on SO is if the question's unclear, to improve it first. OP never clarified whether he wanted to ***"get successive high values (of value?)"""" ordered by order, or by value. I thought he meant ordered by value. Apparently not. Sigh.

Comment: @smci, I think the example and desired output in combination already showed a lot. You could exclude that they only want the data ordered and also it had to be related to the "value" column since the other column was in strictly increasing order already (hence no reason to delete any rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, if I understood the question correct:

```
df[df$value > cummax(c(-Inf, head(df$value, -1))),]
#  order value
#1     1     1
#2     2     7
#5     5     9
#8     8    10
```

I use `cummax` to keep track of the maximum of column "value" and compare it (the previous row's cummax) to each "value" entry. To make sure the first entry is also selected, I start by "-Inf".

Comment: I created a new tag [tag:cumulative-max] for this. Language-agnostic.

Comment: Yes the cum* functions in R are very useful. I had only used cumsum before. Tx again @beginneR

Answer (score 0):

***"get successive high values (of value?)"*** is unclear.
It seems you want to filter only rows whose value is higher than previous max.

First, we reorder your df in increasing order of value... (not clear but I think that's what you wanted)

Then we use logical indexing with `diff()>0` to only include strictly-increasing rows:

```
rdf <- df[order(df$value),]

rdf[ diff(rdf$value)>0, ]
   order value
1      1     1
9      9     2
10    10     3
4      4     5
2      2     7
7      7     9
8      8    10
```

Comment: Not sure this helps. I want extracted out those rows where the value element is of higher value than any previous row - as per my table

Comment: @pssguy: `reordered_df <- df[order(-df$value),]` is exactly what you asked for. You originally asked for decreasing order but apparently now you say you want increasing order.

Comment: Ah I see now: you only want to filter ***rows whose value is higher than previous max***

Comment: Correct Perhaps I could have phrased it better